# Is it possible to heatproof (insulate) stainless steel pot handles?

Tags: equipment, pot

I made a mistake of buying a Cuisinart 6 qt stock pot with two major downsides:  opaque lid (can't see inside) and non-insulated, metal handles.  I wasn't thinking about those features much as I was shopping and the latter now pretty much renders the pot unusable for me because I have a gas stove and the handles get so hot that I have to use a rag or pot holders and I'd rather not have to.

My question is: is there some sort of plastic putty (like [Sugru](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EU7DBNM)) that can be applied over the handles to heatproof it ?  I was thinking maybe electrical tape but I thought that would melt.

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of heat resistant silicon accessories that will serve your purpose.
Here a couple from Amazon.com*

- [Duncan-2-Piece-Short-Handle-Holde](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WIZTWG)
- [JAZ Innovations Cool Touch Lid Handle Cover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000T3QMH8)

  - *Not an endorsement of either Amazon or these products.*

Comment: are these permanent or removable?  i want permanent

Comment: The ones I saw are mostly removable. The JAZ pieces look like they would stay in place until you want to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a product called CopyFlex in the past to do just this.  It's a food-grade silicon rubber that's normally used for mold making, but it coats the handles of cookware just fine if you "rough-up" the surface a bit.

It's a bit of a process, but the results will be quite cheap(if you use the product for more than one use) and you can replace the rubber easily if it gets damaged.  You also may not like the color.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this thread is 2 yrs old but I am married to the guy that holds the patent on heat shrinkable wrap around tubing and you most definitely wrap it around the handles and heat seal the adhesive with a good hair dryer.

Comes in all diameters and sold thru a company he works for called Zippertuning they are in Arizona.

Comment: What's "Az"? Can you include some photos? Or application instruction?

Answer (score -1):

I've used [heat shrink tubing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-shrink_tubing) on a couple of my pieces of cookware. It comes in unshrunk diameters up to at least 1.5" (38 mm). Put the stuff over your handle, hit it with a propane torch or oven burner, and the stuff shrinks to fit snuggly. For more insulation, you can add multiple layers of the stuff. It's available at the usual online outles.

Comment: This won't work on a stockpot due to the loop handles.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Missed the word "stock" there. Still good for other types of handles.